# $ (dollar sign) equivalent for structured notation (Excel Worksheet table)

Tags: excel, structured-references

I'm basically looking for a $A:$A equivalent for structured table references in Excel.

Say I have this formula:

```
=INDEX(tChoice,MATCH(OFFSET(tData[@[cm_sex]],-3,0),tChoice[name],0),3)
```

Basically tData is a table full of raw data (many columns), taken from surveys (so each column is Survey question, more or less). tChoice is a smaller table (just a few columns), I basically want to look up into tChoice the raw data value & return a label based on that (to value-label table is tChoice).

I actually want the tData[@[cm_sex]] to auto-increment as I apply formulas in cells to the left (so I cycle through all the columns of the raw data), however I DON'T want the column tChoice[name] to change: e.g. the column to look for a match based on the raw table data.

This is equivalent to writing, say, A:A (which would auto-increment to B:B, C:C, etc) and $A:$A (which would not).

Is there a dollar sign equivalent for structured table references?

P-S: Of course I can other things like increment the whole thing, than search & replace the range with say tChoice[*] replaced by tChoice[name]... However it would be cleaner & more efficient to have a proper notation for it....

Didn't find it in the support pages (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Using-structured-references-with-Excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e)

Comment: Please try `tChoice[[name]:[name]]`

Comment: When I was trying to solve this problem a couple of years ago I couldn't find a better solution than what you've mentioned.

Comment: Woah actually 3964075 suggestion works, you can do tableName[[columnX]:[columnX]]

Comment: If you can provide an answer I'll accept it, there isn't a lot floating around on this topic.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

user3964075 provided the answer in the comments. I had never seen this before so thanks to him or her for this answer. There's some information out there on the web about absolute structured table references, so I thought I'd summarize what I found.

For your situation you can use `tChoice[[name]:[name]]` Specifying a range that's just the one column anchors the column like $ signs do in normal cell references.

If you want to just deal with one row (the one that the formula is in) the anchor looks like this:`tChoice[@[name]:[name]]`.

Now say you want to anchor one cell but have the other be relative, as in this scenario where I'm summing from `a` to the right, starting with a:a, then a:b, etc:

[image]

You can do that with a formula like this, where the first part is absolute and the second is relative:

```
=SUM(Table1[@[a]:[a]]:Table1[@a])
```

Note that these formulas much be dragged, not copied. Perhaps there is a keyboard shortcut that does this.

This process is rather clunky compared to just clicking F4, as with a regular cell reference. Jon Acampora has created an addin that automates this process, as well as two detailed posts on this topic. [His first post](http://www.excelcampus.com/tips/absolute-formula-references-excel-structured-table/) contains a link to the one with the addin.

Comment: Thanks for the added comments on that - specially the 3rd one I hadn't thought of pushing it this far.

The addin might be useful on my own computer actually, the nice thing being that you don't need to distribute the addin if you're setting up workbooks to distribute....

Comment: That's so true. BTW, I think this is quite a valuable question, since, as you said, there's not much out there on this. I'll be interested to see if it gets many hits over time. Even if not, it sure filled a gap in my knowledge.